# How do I deform a texture?

Tags: java, libgdx, graphics-programming

I'm using LibGDX, and I don't know where to start; I would like to deform a texture.

Let's say I have a PolygonSprite, and I have vertices and a texture.

Image 1 represents what I have. I would like to deform the texture, like in image 2, by changing the position of the vertices. I don't know how to do that, and I don't see the methods for this in the PolygonSprite class.

[image]

I don't want to re-create the vertices, I want to deform the texture based on the first set of created vertices. How do I do that?

Comment: What you're looking for is called texture mapping

Comment: @Bálint what are the libgdx class for manipulate Texture Mapping ?

Comment: I'm oretty sure you have to create a mesh with uv coordinates

Comment: @Bálint ok, do you have a tutorial, where I can get started please